# Query about finding an expression for dV

Tags: calculus

I was trying to prove the hydrostatic equilibrium relationship, the only way I found that it works, and I saw this done by someone online too, was by saying that $dV=dA \ dr$. But if $V=Ar$ then surely $dV=rdA+Adr$.

How can we say $dV=dAdr$ here?
[Source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qZzu.png)

Comment: $V=Ar$ is irrelevant. There is nothing in the diagram labeled $A$ or $V$. $dV = dA\;dr$ is just "the volume of a cylinder = base area $\times$ height".

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}r}=\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}r}r+A\cdot1=A,$$
where $\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}r}=0$ ($A$ stays constant over $r$!), so $$\mathrm{d}V=A\,\mathrm{d}r$$
(or $\mathrm{d}V=\mathrm{d}A\,\mathrm{d}r$ if you call the area $\mathrm{d}A$ instead of $A$, like in the image).